# Where is the JAR packaging Maven lifecycle defined?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-lifecycle

I'm creating a custom Maven packaging based on the lifecycle of the JAR packaging. I'd like to known where this lifecycle is defined (i.e. `components.xml` source code location).

Comment: Why are you creating a custom packaging?

Comment: My team need to automate the build process (compile, run tests, package and deploy) of PL/SQL projects. Maven is flexible enough to be used with non Java projects too. So, we are starting to create some custom plugins and a new packaging type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a small misconception in your question. The `"jar"` packaging doesn't have a special lifecycle. It is based on the default lifecycle.

From [the lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html):

> Maven defines 3 lifecycles in `META-INF/plexus/components.xml`:
>
> - `default` Lifecycle
> - `clean` Lifecycle
> - `site` Lifecycle

You can find this `components.xml` file in the source code [here for Maven 3.3.9](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml#L30-L64). The `default` lifecycle does not define any bindings since they depend on the packaging:

> `default` lifecycle is defined **without** any associated plugin. Plugin bindings for this lifecycle are [defined separately for every packaging](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

Each of the standard packaging (like `"jar"`) defines plugins that are bound to specific phases of this default lifecycle. You can find those bindings inside the file [`default-bindings.xml`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml#L59-L98).

The goal of having those two separate files is to make a distinction between the lifecycle, which defines what phases it includes, and the packaging, which defines which goals of a plugin should be bound to which phases of that lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks. My misconception was based on this online book:

https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html

It uses the expression "Package-specific Lifecycles", but I agree with your point.

Comment: @FernandoCosta This Maven book is a very good resource. Yeah the title "Package-specific Lifecycles" might a bit misleading (because it is just the default one) but the text after is correct. It is the configuration of the lifecycle that changes, not the lifecycle itself.

Comment: Why did someone capable of remove my comment of 8-10 hrs ago? It was: Re "_which plugin should be bound to which phases_" – Isn't it that _goals_ (of plugins) are bound to phases?